# Importing worksheets into one excel workbook

Tags: excel, copy-paste

I have a folder with 111 excel work books. I want to copy and paste every file into one excel file into separate sheets. So one sheet should have the contents of one file. Each file contains only one sheet. Any ideas would help as i am not very familiar with VBA. And I don't want to copy and paste 111 times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently. This code is all you need. Specify a folder and it will combine all workbooks into one (handles them even if they have multiple sheets, too).

```vb
' found at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=829

Option Explicit

 '32-bit API declarations
Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal _
pszpath As String) As Long

Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BrowseInfo) _
As Long

Public Type BrowseInfo
    hOwner As Long
    pIDLRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As Long
    lParam As Long
    iImage As Long
End Type

Function GetDirectory(Optional msg) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim bInfo As BrowseInfo
    Dim path As String
    Dim r As Long, x As Long, pos As Integer

     'Root folder = Desktop
    bInfo.pIDLRoot = 0&

     'Title in the dialog
    If IsMissing(msg) Then
        bInfo.lpszTitle = "Please select the folder of the excel files to copy."
    Else
        bInfo.lpszTitle = msg
    End If

     'Type of directory to return
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1

     'Display the dialog
    x = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo)

     'Parse the result
    path = Space$(512)
    r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal x, ByVal path)
    If r Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetDirectory = Left(path, pos - 1)
    Else
        GetDirectory = ""
    End If
End Function

Sub CombineFiles()
    Dim path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim LastCell        As range
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim ThisWB          As String

    ThisWB = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    path = GetDirectory
    FileName = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        If FileName <> ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path & "\" & FileName)
            For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets
                Set LastCell = ws.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
                If LastCell.Value = "" And LastCell.Address = range("$A$1").Address Then
                Else
                    ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
                End If
            Next ws
            Wkb.Close False
        End If
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set Wkb = Nothing
    Set LastCell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me a an error "Run-time error 1004": Method 'Copy' of object'_Worksheet' failed"

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter version. You'll need to do Tools/References and add Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Sub CopySheet1s()
' Copies first sheet from all workbooks in current path
' to a new workbook called wbOutput.xlsx

Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject    
Dim vFile As Variant, sFile As String, lPos As Long
Dim wbInput As Workbook, wbOutput As Workbook
Dim fFolder As Folder
Const cOUTPUT As String = "wbOutput.xlsx"

    If fso.FileExists(cOUTPUT) Then
        fso.DeleteFile cOUTPUT
    End If

    Set wbOutput = Workbooks.Add()        

    Set fFolder = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
    For Each vFile In fFolder.Files
        lPos = InStrRev(vFile, "\")
        sFile = Mid(vFile, lPos + 1)
        If sFile <> cOUTPUT And sFile <> ThisWorkbook.Name And Left(sFile, 1) <> "~" Then
            Set wbInput = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile, ReadOnly:=True)
            wbInput.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=wbOutput.Worksheets(1)
            wbInput.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    Next

    wbOutput.SaveAs Filename:=cOUTPUT
    wbOutput.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place all your .xls files into one folder, enter the files path in 'Enter Files Path Here' and run the macro.

```
Sub GetSheets()

Path = "C:\Enter Files Path Here\"

Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

 Next Sheet

 Workbooks(Filename).Close

 Filename = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```